# Using script with Lightning Component

Tags: lightning, community, aura, lightning-container

I am trying to create a twitter feed component for use in Salesforce communities and because I need to use the JS supplied by Twitter I am using a Lightning:container, however I cannon't seem to get the JS to load for me and I have been trying for days.

I have created an index.html file and zipped that up with the "widgets.js" file supplied by Twitter and saved it to the static resources in a file called spptest. I have also whitelisted twitter in the community CSP. Please see my code below and If you can spot any issues with it please let me know.

Thanks,
James

**HTML**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>
    <a class="twitter-timeline" href="https://twitter.com/TwitterDev?ref_src=twsrc%5Etfw">Tweets by TwitterDev</a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**CMP**

```
    <aura:component implements="forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes, flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes" access="global">
        <lightning:container src="{!$Resource.spptest + 'index.html'}"/>
        <aura:attribute name="TwitterHandle" type="String" />

    </aura:component>
```

**Design**

```
    <design:component label="Twitter Feed 2.0">
        <design:attribute name="TwitterHandle" label="Twitter Handle" description="Please insert the Twitter handle you would like to display" />
        <design:supportedFormFactors>
            <design:supportedFormFactor type="Large"/>
            <design:supportedFormFactor type="Small"/>
        </design:supportedFormFactors>
    </design:component>
```

This is the result I get when the component is in the community:

[image: Screengrab of test community]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not directly use widget js in the lightning component. because of CSP
[image]

As a workaround, you can create a VF page and call it using iframe in component

VF Page

```
<apex:page id="TwittweFeed" showHeader="false">
    <apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.twitterwidget}"/>

    <a class="twitter-timeline" data-link-color="#19CF86" href="https://twitter.com/tweeterhandlename?lang=en"></a>
</apex:page>
```

Lightning Component

```
<aura:component implements="flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes">
    <iframe src="PATH_TO_VF_PAGE/apex/samplePage" width="100%" height="800px"/>
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Thanks Anmol! This works a treat